# All page across domain require HTTPS

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, https

I just bought SSL for my domain and the host installed it and now all pages are requiring "HTTPS". Is there a way to fix this globally and only display the https pages when I call for them?

Example:

example.com - wont work
https://example.com - works

I know I have to link to the pages I want secure with https, none of the pages are working though and host wont help.

Comment: What do you mean won't work? What happens when you access non http. And if they don't have support might be time for a new host.

Comment: @PanamaJack It gives a page not found error. If I type https:// it works. Yes I agree but I just paid them today :-(

Comment: Do you run a control panel? It might not be recognizing the http vhost anymore.

Comment: No control panel. Its a basic site, i just wanted to secure login, registration and member pages

Comment: Did you change the IP address at all when you added the cert and updated the vhost?

Comment: The host did all that and yes, I had to get a private ip

Comment: make sure both your vhosts for 80 and 443 are using the same IP. What web server are you using?

Comment: Awardspace, they were great free, now that I'm close to launching everything has gone to crap. As far as I can tell, its a hosting issue, they are telling me its not.

Comment: I meant what is the web server not host. Apache, nginx?

Comment: Waiting on Awrdspace to respond, not in any of the documentation.

Comment: That host sound like a crap shared hosting. I'd use Linode and get a cloud server that's not shared for the same amount of money. Plus AwardSpace says "All our hosting plans have 30 days money back guarantee**" There is no reason to be fighting.

Comment: @PanamaJack they are telling me the DNS has not fully propagated yet. Does this sound right? Seems neither would work if that was the case.

Comment: I don't believe it has to do with DNS. You can even check here http://dnschecker.org. As I said, they don't seem to have a clue. It's most likely a configuration issue with the vhost listening on 80. I wouldn't trust that host with my site.

Comment: The first selection at "A" at DNS checker passed, everything after failed

Comment: Yes, you are only checking for A record. That is what maps hostname to IP address. The other records don't matter in the case. So it's not a DNS problem.

Answer (score 0):

it’s important to avoid this by
ensuring that every image, CSS and Javscript file on a secure
page is accessed using HTTPS. For content on the same domain it’s quite straightforward – you just need to use relative URLs. A relative URL contains the ‘offset’ URL that
needs to be applied to the page’s absolute URL in order to
find a resource.

A problem arises though, if you attempt to access a
resource from a different domain because you can’t use the
simple path-relative URL to access the resource. This often
happens when you attempt to use a third party service such
as Google Analytics or a third party Ajax library CDN.
Google Analytics solves the problem with its external
javascript file by recommending the use of this code to
dynamically switch protocols:

```
var gast = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
"https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gast +
"google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

Comment: What in the blazes are you talking about? Did you even read his issue or the conversation?

Comment: Thats not the issue but thanks. I'll describe a little better Whenever I try to access any page via http only, it throws a "page not found" error. If I use https the pages come up. This is across the whole domain. Just because they installed SSL for me does not mean that every single page should be https

Comment: Redirect from http to https

This bit will help you tremendously when you’ve not updated every single link in your site yet. You can just add a straight server level redirect from http to https. In Apache you’d do something like this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Redirect from http to https

This bit will help you tremendously when you’ve not updated every single link in your site yet. You can just add a straight server level redirect from http to https.

In Apache you’d do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can force https acces with htaccess. Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Please replace `www.yourdomain.com` with that of yours'

**Note:** Please do remeber to get your mod_rewrite ON for the server

Comment: That's not what he's asking for. He wants to be able to access non https links. That's why I asked him what was happening first.

Comment: https access is on all the time I want http acces on always and https when I call it